# Mail methode in a cronjob task command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello I try to send an email with an excel file from a command but it's seems to doesn't work

i get this exception when i try to run the artisan command :

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::subject()

someone now how to resolve the problem ? thanks a lot in advance

here my command :

```
 public function handle()
 {
     $user = Auth::user();

     $licencies = Licencies::where('lb_assurance' , '=' , 'Lafont')
         ->where('created_at' , Carbon::today())->get();

     $excel_file = Excel::create('DailyRecapLicencesLafont', 
         function($excel) use ($licencies) {
             $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies) {
                $sheet->fromArray($licencies);
             });
          });

        Mail::to($user)
            ->subject('Licences Lafont Daily')
            ->from('test@test.fr')
            ->attach($excel_file , 'LaFontDaily.xls')
            ->send();

        $this->info('Lafont task Done');
    }
```

Comment: which laravel version?

Comment: i use L 5.4 !!!

Comment: Your Mail facade usage is not correct, please check the docs for sending raw emails: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail

Comment: i created a mail methode with mark down i tried this :  public function handle()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        $licencies = Licencies::where('lb_assurance' , '=' , 'Lafont')->where('created_at' , Carbon::today())->get();

        Mail::to($user)->send(new LicenceLaFont($licencies));

        $this->info('Lafont task Done');
    }  but it tells me that i can't Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\LicenceLaFont::__construct() must be an instance of App\Licencies, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given,

Comment: could me explain my the best way to do what i did who don't work now with laravel 5.4 .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Mail like this:

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function ($m) use ($user, $excel_file) {
    $m->to($user->email);
    $m->subject('Licences Lafont Daily');
    $m->from('test@test.fr');
    $m->attachData($excel_file->string() , 'LaFontDaily.xls');
});
```

Source: [laravel 5.1 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail), still valid in large part for 5.4

Not sure if $excel_file is a in memory data, so its better if you save the file before and call:

```
 $m->attach($path_to_file , 'LaFontDaily.xls');
```

Side note: `Auth::user()` should return nothing in a command so it is better if you use a predefined email address in the to() function.

Comment: can't acces to $user also !

Comment: i get try to get property of non object

Comment: as I added in the answer Auth::user() in a command returns null so $user is null